# DataTables- adding HTML elements outside of table

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I'm trying to add a button that will download the table as an .xls file.
I found this page but when I add the JS that it shows, nothing happens: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    dom:
      "<'row' <'col-md-12'i>>" +
      "<'row' <'col-md-6'B>>" +
      "<'row' <'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row' <'col-md-12'p>>",
    buttons: [
      'excel'
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean? Do you see the button? Are there any errors in the browser console? (I cannot recreate your issue - your code works for me).

Comment: Have you included the relevant "buttons" resources on your page? You can use the official [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index) to generate all of the required script and CSS resources you need for Buttons to work.

Comment: @andrewjames The button doesn't appear at all. I've made a lot of edits to the CSS, so I wonder if something is hiding the button.

Comment: OK - but first things first: Have you included the relevant "buttons" resources on your page...? If you have, then strip out all those "css edits" until it works (as it does for me) and then start adding them back in, one by one.

Comment: Also, in the example you linked to, there are eight required files below the example (javascript tab). Do you have all of those added to your page? Edit: Already asked above, but unanswered. I'll leave it here.

Comment: I guess one of those links or scripts was missing because it did work when I added them all again. It's probably because the file I was working with already had some of these scripts and I thought one was there when it really wasn't. Thanks for the help, it was very useful to know that it worked for other people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enclose your JS with the "script" tag? Maybe I'm stating the obvious, but it's happened to me before.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    dom:
      "<'row' <'col-md-12'i>>" +
      "<'row' <'col-md-6'B>>" +
      "<'row' <'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row' <'col-md-12'p>>",
    buttons: [
      'excel'
    ]
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, everything works fine, but the button won't show

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code. The HTML and CSS.

Comment: I figured it out. One of the links to the CSS or JS was missing. Thanks for reaching out!